# System.Net.WebExceptionStatus Exception in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am trying to login using **HttpClient**. I am using cellular data connection (3G) to send the data to my server. When I use data instead of a Wifi connection this error comes up. What are the causes of this? and how can I avoid this in the future?

> System.Net.WebException: at System.Net.WebConnection.HandleError (System.Net.WebExceptionStatus st, System.Exception e, System.String where) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Net.WebConnection.ReadDone (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult+<>c.b__27_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in <3ba84c786fec4b0f80feecce6261cf51>:0 at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00000] in <3ba84c786fec4b0f80feecce6261cf51>:0 at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <3ba84c786fec4b0f80feecce6261cf51>:0

```
 var link = "http://" + ipaddress + Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + hostName + "&Database=" + database + "&Request=7ZEGvK";
 string contentType = "application/json";
 JObject json = new JObject
 {
    { "User", userName },
    { "Password", password },
    { "Code", Constants.deviceID }
 };

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));
```

Comment: There can't be any differences in the wifi and 3g connection aside from speed and stability. So the question should be either updated or closed.

Comment: You can try putting a `try/catch` around your `HttpClient` and catching `WebException`s. You should then check the `Response` and/or `Status` properties of the exception to handle and determine what is causing the issue.

Comment: @IvanIčin What is the cause of this exception?

Comment: @Tom I did put the code inside a try/catch the problem is when I click the login button the error occurs

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Did you check the contents of the exception? If so, put them in the question.

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto it cannot be said with the details that you provided.

Comment: @Tom the contents of the exception is already in the question

Comment: @IvanIčin what details do you need? I can provide it

Comment: please read @Tom comment again, he is making a specific suggestion for you to try and you're just ignoring it.  And what you posted is just the stack trace

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto, yes Tom's advice.

Comment: Do you have the necessary services to use 3G mobile data?